# Wordpress breadcrumb with Custom post Type category and children in the category

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, categories, breadcrumbs

I'm trying to create custom breadcrumbs on my Wordpress project.
I searched around and found satisfactory examples, like [Dimox Breadcrumbs](https://gist.github.com/Dimox/5654092).

The problem is that I have custom post types that are recalled on a page with a parent.
The various CPTs are associated with categories, daughters of other categories.
When I print the breadcrumbs, however, in the CPT I find only the path from Home> Subcategory> CPT but not all the fathers pages I have served to get there.
Do you have any idea how to structure it?
O example ??

Thank you

Comment: Use this one https://wordpress.org/plugins/breadcrumb-navxt/

Comment: Already used, does not satisfy what I want.

He prints me Home> Category> CPT.
I would like Home> Page> Page> Page of cpt> Category> CPT